# MasterDetailPage xamarin.forms flow direction right to left not working on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I Have a MasterDetailPage on Xamarin.Forms and I switched the flow direction to RightToLeft. It works as expected on UWP and iOS but not on Android. Anyone knows why? On Android it still showing as LeftToRight...

Comment: This issue seems will appear on Hamburger Icon .Here is a similar issue maybe can help you https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2818.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Xamarin Documentation [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left)
you should set supportsRtl to true in the application manifest in android project

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

and if you want to enforce supporting RTL without changing device language you should add this code to your MainActivity.cs in "OnCreate" Method

```
Window.DecorView.LayoutDirection = LayoutDirection.Rtl;
```